# 'float' object is not iterable in NLP

Tags: python-3.x, nlp

I am working on a natural language processing project. The purpose of the code is to remove all punctuation in the data set. But an error was reported when calling the function. What is the reason?

```
def remove_punct(text):
    text_nopunct = ''.join([char for char in text if char not in string.punctuation])
    return text_nopunct

data['body_text_clean'] = data['body_text'].apply(lambda x: remove_punct(x))
```

Comment: what was the specific error message you got when running it? I run your code in my test and it works fine. did you `import string`?

Comment: `''.join([char for char in str(text) if char not in string.punctuation])` also try str(text) to typecast non-string variables.

Comment: Thank you very much, using str(text) solved my problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm just restating what was in the comments for the community. The solved answer in the comments was:

"`''.join([char for char in str(text) if char not in string.punctuation])` also try str(text) to typecast non-string variables."
By Earlee